What is this tree with these red berries?
I recently moved to a new house, and adjacent to our roof terrace is a tree that is giving fruit in the form of berries.
I'm wondering what tree it is/berries they are.
Initially I thought cranberries, but there is a hard pit inside.
Can anybody help me identify the tree?







Based on the veining in the leaves, the tree is a dogwood. which leads to the ID of a Cornelian Cherry or Cornel, Cornus mas. It would've had bright yellow flowers in the spring.

Thank you! This is correct, we looked back at pictures earlier this year and it indeed had bright yellow flowers. I'll add the picture to the OP

Edible fruits BTW. But I would not eat them. Traditions tell us you can make jam, but you need a lot (really a lot) of sugar, and probably you will not like. Possibly there are many other uses, but now we uses it mostly for decoration, or as ruderal plant (birds plant it everywhere)

I tried some and found it not too bad. A bit sour, but not too extreme to prevent enjoyment.
